# How to manually install translations files on WooCommerce 2.2+?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the WooCommerce plugin to display french text (`fr_FR`). The rest of Wordpress is correctly set to french but WooCommerce still shows english.

Since version 2.2 language packs are not included. This message is displayed on the admin page:

[image: woocommerce translation available]

The recommended automatic "Update translation" procedure involves giving FTP access to my server which I would like to avoid.

There are `fr_FR` translations available in the WooCommerce git repo:

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce-language-packs/raw/master/packages/fr_FR.zip

I've unziped that in the same folder as the default english language files.

```
$ ls -l wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages 
total 1320
-rw-r--r-- 1 knarf users 211452 24 sept. 18:01 fr_FR.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 knarf users 116765 22 sept. 10:48 woocommerce-admin-fr_FR.mo
-rw-r--r-- 1 knarf users 211901 22 sept. 10:48 woocommerce-admin-fr_FR.po
-rw-r--r-- 1 knarf users 162575 18 sept. 14:48 woocommerce-admin.pot
-rw-r--r-- 1 knarf users 163575 22 sept. 10:48 woocommerce-fr_FR.mo
-rw-r--r-- 1 knarf users 268719 22 sept. 10:48 woocommerce-fr_FR.po
-rw-r--r-- 1 knarf users 208795 18 sept. 14:48 woocommerce.pot
```

I've tried setting `WPLANG` to french in `wp-config.php`:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR');
```

Despite all this, The "WooCommerce Translation Available" message is still there and WooCommerce interface is still in english. How do I force WooCommerce to switch to french?

Running the "Force Update Translation" procedure (from the message) fails with:

> Failed to install/update the translation: An authentication error occurred while updating the translation. Please try again or configure your Upgrade Constants.

I'm using a fresh install of WordPress 4.0 (french release) and WooCommerce 2.2.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Translation Docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/)

> PO and MO files will be downloaded in
>   wp-content/languages/woocommerce.

So the woocommerce plugin folder is the wrong place to upload the language pack.

**Edit: Important note concerning Language codes**

Per @Julian Moreno's comment, the language code (and subsequent code) for WooCommerce must match the code you are using for WordPress.

> In my case WordPress is "es_MX" and WooCommerce must be also "es_MX".

Comment: Sometimes you just need fresh eyes.

Comment: @helgatheviking Could you please provide us a step by step process? I've placed the **.po** and **.mo** files in the following directory paths "`wp-content/languages/woocommerce/`" and "`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages/`", and then clicked on the button "Force translation upgrade", but the error persists:
![Failed to install/update the translation](http://i.imgur.com/dlDgBt8.png)

Comment: It's done. Language pack from WordPress must be the same language pack as WooCommerce. In my case WordPress is "es_MX" and WooCommerce must be also "es_MX".

Answer (score 0):

I had the **same issue** when I have changed WooCommerce basic language from English To Danish. Til after that it was showing English rather than Danish for WooCommerce Pages.

Then I noticed from this tutorial [WooCommerce Translate Language](http://guruquest.net/question/how-to-translate-wordpress-woocommerce-language/?utm_source=StackOverflow&utm_medium=StackOverflow&utm_campaign=StackOverflow)

I had to place **WooCommerce plugin translation files at**

> 'wp-content/languages/plugin/woocommerce'